# Minimal family of hash functions

Tags: algorithm, math, hash, cryptography, hashtable

Please tell me how to find out minimal number of functions included in family of hash functions for sets: 
`{1..n} -> {1..m}`
 I know defintion, I know that there are many families but I can't find how to construct MINIMAL family.

It will be nice if anyone could show me process of constructing such a family on example: `{1,2,3,4}->{1,2}`

Please help me! Greetings M.

Comment: I really don't understand the question. What would be the attributes of a minimal family mapping *{1, 2, 3, 4} -> {1, 2}*. Obviously, there *will* be collisions. Is the function that maps all of them to 1 part of the family?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about crypto theory rather than programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks guys for your replies, I finally come up with idea how to do `MINIMAL family of hashing functions`. 
The `minimal`, in that context, means that no function could be deleted from that family to keep condition on family of hashing functions. For example, for `{1,2,3,4} -> {1,2}` the number of functions in minimal family is 6. For example, table of functions values:

`1 1 2 1`
`1 2 1 2`
`1 2 2 1`
`2 2 1 1`
`2 1 2 1`
`2 1 1 2`

Each segment represents values of another function.

Answer (score 1):

Curious question, or not well asked ?

**Hashing functions essentially map (1..m) to (1..n)** . **Any** function can do that, then be a hashing function. n is less than m !

When one talk about *family*, it is kind of *algorithm* ...

**So total number of functions** is any function which gets 1..n, so any partition with n subsets: exercise. any partition with n or less than n subsets = m^n. Tip: Compare with any partition with n-1 or less than n-1 subsets.

**Minimal = 1 : any mapping !**

**General number of functions** : generally, hash functions are uniform, so each subset must have m/n elements. So number = Cm,m/n x C (m-m/n),m/n x C (m-km/n), m/n ...